# argparse: Ignore positional arguments if a flag is set?

Tags: python, argparse

I want to provide the command with 3 arguments: `<version>`, `<input file>` and `<output file>` under normal usage. Except there's a specific flag `--init`, which will basically run the program without any input and output file specifications required.

I would therefore ideally have a command which usage is:

`py program.py --init`

OR

`py program.py <version> <input file> <output file>`

However, since positional arguments are always required (because all 3 are required in any other circumstance than `--init`), there seems to be no way to cleanly get this syntax and all I could think of would be to make the 3 positional arguments into an optional flag, raise an exception if the optional flag isn't there when `--init` is not called. And that all seems ugly.

My code so far:

```
def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Tool for FOO-ing a BAR.")
    parser.add_argument(dest="version", help="The version.")
    parser.add_argument(dest="input", help="The input file.")
    parser.add_argument(dest="output", help="The output file.")

    parser.add_argument("-i", "--init", dest="init", action="store_true", help="Foo Init.")

    return parser.parse_args()
```

**To Clarify:**
Either all 3 arguments (`<version> <input> <output>`) MUST be specified.
OR
The program is only ran with `--init` flag and 0 arguments should be specified.

The program should NOT accept with 0, 1 or 2 arguments specified (without the `--init` flag).

Comment: A similar recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60914777/how-to-take-two-positional-arguments-when-optinal-isnt-set-in-argparse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your own action class:

```py
class init_action(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, **kwargs):
        return super().__init__(option_strings, dest, nargs=0, default=argparse.SUPPRESS, **kwargs)
    
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string, **kwargs):
        # Do whatever should be done here
        parser.exit()

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Tool for FOO-ing a BAR.")
    parser.add_argument(dest="version", help="The version.")
    parser.add_argument(dest="input", help="The input file.")
    parser.add_argument(dest="output", help="The output file.")

    parser.add_argument("-i", "--init", action=init_action, help="Foo Init.")

    return parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and fixed it by adding `nargs="?"` to all my positional arguments

```py
def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Tool for FOO-ing a BAR.")
    parser.add_argument(dest="version", nargs="?", help="The version.")
    parser.add_argument(dest="input", nargs="?", help="The input file.")
    parser.add_argument(dest="output", nargs="?", help="The output file.")

    parser.add_argument("-i", "--init", dest="init", action="store_true", help="Foo Init.")

    return parser.parse_args()
```

but I'm not completely satisfied with it since when you run

```
py program.py -h
```

the synopsys is printed as

```
usage: program.py [-h] [--init] [version] [input] [output]
```

while I would want it to be

```
usage: program.py [-h] [--init] version input output
```

since `version`, `input` and `output` are required, just that they are not required when you use the `--init` flag.

Another downside is that you do not get the help text printed if you do not provide the positional arguments correctly.

I think it is sad that argparse have no way to set `ignore_positional_args=True` or something on flags. Especially since this property already is true for the `-h` flag. At least I'm not able to find a way to do it.

**EDIT:**

I actually found a way to better way to do it, but put it in a separate answer because I think this can be a useful approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `sys.argv` to determine whether the flag is enabled.
Using your example,

```
import sys

if '--init' not in sys.argv:
    parser.add_argument(dest="version", help="The version.")
    parser.add_argument(dest="input", help="The input file.")
    parser.add_argument(dest="output", help="The output file.")
```

Argparse will allow you to run the program with either `--init` flag without any arguments or force you to include other arguments if `--init` flag is not present.

One downside to this approach is that you will see the following output, when you run `py program.py -h`:

```
usage: program.py [--init] version input output

positional arguments:
  version - The version.
  input - The input file.
  output - The output file.

optional arguments:
  --init - ...
```

which makes it hard for the user to understand the logic unless you clarify it in the description in the help section.

Answer (score 0):

**parser.add_argument** has a **default** parameter ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument)) which can be used here for *version, input and output* parameters. Now you won't need third *init* param

Comment: I think you misunderstood the use of init. Init does something that doesn't require a version, input and output parameter. It simply doesn't use them, but it just does some init stuff and exits the program. However when you run it under normal circumstances, you are required to specify the 3 parameters. If you don't then the program has no clue what to do. If I simply set these parameters to a default value, then it will give undefined behavior to the user.

Comment: well in that case also ...you can check if all the three attributes have default value then you can trigger init  and do the init stuff and exit the program.

Comment: That's still bad, what if the user only specifies a version, but not an input and output?

Comment: you would be checking that all three have default value then only you would trigger init !

Comment: But then I would have to raise my own exception when not all 3 are default. I would ideally like argparse to accept only with 3 arguments given rather than sniff out the user input myself.